LuaTeX & citeproc: attempt to concatenate a nil value
I am working with LuaTex and citeproc to generate formatted references using a custom CSL file. I have tried to compile both locally via my texlive installation (and using Kile) and online via Overleaf to see if there is any difference (and there is none). Here is a minimal example from which I receive the error:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}

% Load your .bib file
\addbibresource{references.bib}

% Specify the CSL file
\cslsetup{style=custom_style}

\begin{document}

According to \citep{ref1} \citep{ref2} \citep{ref3}

% Print the bibliography
\printbibliography

\end{document}

And both locally and online, I receive the following error:
...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-locale.lua:136: attempt to concatenate a nil value (local 'key')
stack traceback:
    ...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-locale.lua:136: in function <...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-locale.lua:128>
    (...tail calls...)
    .../scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-label.lua:77: in method 'build_ir'
    ...ist/scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-element.lua:196: in method 'build_group_ir'
    .../scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-group.lua:47: in method 'build_ir'
    ...ist/scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-element.lua:196: in method 'build_group_ir'
    .../scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-group.lua:47: in method 'build_ir'
    ...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-choose.lua:170: in method 'build_children_ir'
    ...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-choose.lua:214: in method 'build_ir'
    ...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-choose.lua:58: in method 'build_ir'
    ...ist/scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-element.lua:161: in method 'build_children_ir'
    ...scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-layout.lua:49: in method 'build_ir'
    ...s/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-bibliography.lua:155: in method 'build_ir'
    ...s/citation-style-language/citeproc-node-bibliography.lua:132: in method 'build_bibliography_str'
    ...dist/scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-engine.lua:753: in method 'makeBibliography'
    .../scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-latex-core.lua:434: in function 'citeproc-latex-core.make_bibliography'
    ...-dist/scripts/citation-style-language/citeproc-latex.lua:169: in function 'citeproc-latex.bibliography'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\lua_now:e #1->\__lua_now:n {#1}

... which results in an empty bibliography.
I have no idea what possible troubleshooting steps to follow here, since it is not an issue related to the installation of my distribution. I assume the issue is related to how citeproc reads the csl file, but I do not know how to debug this, and would appreciate suggestions at where to start. Also, the csl file is provided by my university, which has previously worked with Zotero without issue when integrating with Word.

Welcome! Does it work with one of the styles provided by the package? Does it work with the custom style and a minimal bib? Can you provide a link to the custom style? If so, can you also provide a minimal .bib we can use to reproduce the problem? The package does say that not all features of CSL are implemented yet, so perhaps your uni's file uses one of those?

It's likely to be a mistyped "form" attribute in the <locale> part in the CSL style.
